# strapi + knex to execute complex Queries

Tags: strapi

How do  I get the knex object to execute custom or complex queries within my strapi service?

My Strapi version has the `strapi-hook-knex` and `strapi-hook-bookshelf` installed but when I run `qb.raw` it is an undefined object.

This is to run queries like this:

```
qb.select(knex.raw('.... ?? )', '...'))
```

Answer (score 9):

You will find it in `strapi.connections.default`

`default` if you don't change your connection name. If you did you will have to replace `default` by your connection name.

Comment: It doesn't work with strapi v4.0.7, on my v3.6.5 it was working fine

Answer (score 7):

Took me awhile to pin down exact syntax for this. Here it is in case helpful to others. Could not have gotten there without Jim LAURIE's answer.

```
module.exports = {
  async findCustom(ctx) {
    const rawBuilder = strapi.connections.default.raw(
      "select field1 from mytable where field1 = 'x'"
    );
    const resp = await rawBuilder.then();
    return resp.rows;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> in strapi V4 use this:

```
await strapi.db.connection.select("*").from("demos")
```

Answer (score 2):

With Strapi v4 use:

```
strapi.db.connection.raw
```

instead of

```
strapi.connections.default.raw
```

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(strapi.db.connection.raw("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.mytable").then(r => { console.log(r) }, error => {console.log(error)}))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
async findCustom(ctx) {
  const rawBuilder = (await strapi.db.connection.select().count().from("users_links").where({group_id:5}));

  try {
    ctx.body = rawBuilder;
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.body = err;
  }
}
```